# How to translate this particular in_array PHP code into Twig template code

Tags: twig

I have this code:

```
<?php if ((in_array('name1', (array)$settings)) && (in_array('name2', (array)$settings))) { ?>
```

As well as this one:

```
<?php if ((in_array('name1', (array)$this->config->get('settings'))) && (in_array('name2', (array)$this->config->get(settings')))) { ?>
```

How can this be written in Twig?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In twig you can write

```
{% if 'needle' in haystack and ... %}
    Oh Yeah!
{% endif %}
```